# Accessing BSTR in SAFEARRAY

Tags: c++, com, safearray

I am getting a SAFEARRAY ** which should contain "GOOG" and "O"

It looks good in the debugger

[image]

However I cannot get the BSTRs out!

This code

```
      BSTR * raw;
      HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(*Strings, (void **)&raw);
```

gives me

[image]

which crashes if i continue to dereference the raw pointer

I get the exact same result doing it by hand

```
BSTR* t2 = (BSTR*)(*Strings)->pvData;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After much experimentation, The answer seems to be that you have to extract the strings as VARIANTS and later on convert them to BSTRs and then finally to wstrings.

Something like this

```
// access data as an array of variants
VARIANT * raw;
SafeArrayAccessData(*Strings, (void **)&raw);

// convert to a BSTR wrapper
const _bstr_t wrapper(raw[0]); 

// convert to a wstring
std::wstring wstrVal((const wchar_t*)wrapper);
```

Or, in one fell swoop as suggested by Hans Passant

```
// access data 
VARIANT * raw;
SafeArrayAccessData(*Strings, (void **)&raw);
std::wstring wstrVal((const wchar_t*)raw[0].bstrVal);
```

Comment: Yup, the debugger showed you the value of VARIANT.vt.  8 means "variant containing a VT_BSTR".  Little point in burning cycles and heap with _bstr_t, just use raw[0].bstrVal directly.

Comment: It would be better to use V_BSTR(&raw[0]) rather than raw[0].bstrVal.